# jQuery call click function manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click

I'd like to call a click function manually.

```
$('.back').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Is it possible to give the function above a name to call it or is the only way using a trigger like this:

```
$('.back').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define you function out side of the click function

```
function clickFunction() {
    ...
}
$('.back').click(clickFunction);
...
clickFunction();
```

Of course when you call it manually there is no event object and the the function is not bound to the `.back` element.

Comment: It should, show your code so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 2):

the click() function take a function as an argument.

```
function myClickHandler() {
    ...
}

$('.back').click(myClickHandler);
```

You can call myClickHandler as a normal function too.